# What is the command to call Spark2 from Shell

Tags: apache-spark

I have two services for Spark in my cluster, one is with name of Spark(1.6 version) and another one is Spark2(2.0 Version). I am able to call Spark with below command.

spark-shell --master yarn

But not able to connect Spark2 service even after set "export SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2"

Can some one help me on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using CDH cluster and following command works for me.

```
spark2-shell --queue <queue-name-if-any> --deploy-mode client
```

Comment: Even me using CDH cluster and the above command working for me. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

If I remember, `SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION` only works with `spark-submit`

You would need to find the spark2 installation directory to use the other `spark-shell`

Sounds like you are in an HDP cluster, so look under `/usr/hdp`

Comment: Hello, I am using CDH cluster.

Comment: Same thing nowadays, but as the other answer shows, there's a separate script for the other shell